# Add plugins using cli in cordova 2.5.0

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have tried my best to add a plugins using Command line interface in cordova 2.5.0 but failed to find any solution can u please help me to add plugins

Comment: i want to add plugin of barcode

Comment: Have you tried this one? `cordova plugin add https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner.git` I believe this version is 2.X compatible. Also, is there a reason why you are using 2.5? Most of the plugins have been updated for 3.X and it's usually as simple as starting a new 3.X project and copying over your `www` folder from your older project to update. But I understand sometimes it's not possible based on the project.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can use the command line to manage cordova 2.5 projects. The node base CLI didn't get added to the project until cordova 2.9.0.

You need to manually add plugins as outlined here:  https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide